# Optionally static class method for interface compatibility

Tags: powershell

I've defined a custom ValidateSet parameter attribute like so:

```
Class MyValidValuesAttribute : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues() { return [string[]]'MyValidValueA','MyValidValueB' }
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to instantiate the class just to return the set of valid values.

I'd simply call `[MyValidValuesAttribute]::GetValidValues()` instead of the two-line

```
$X = [MyValidValuesAttribute]::new()
$Y = $X.GetValidValues()
```

but that method must not be static or the class will not implement the interface.

Is there any way to make a method work the same way regardless of whether the class has been instantiated *under the same name*? I know I could just implement `GetValidValues_Static`; wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: `([MyValidValuesAttribute]::new()).GetValidValues()` works, but I still wonder if a method is strictly static/non-static, because a valid constructor could be long & complex while the class' interface method implementation doesn't require any of them.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on why, in this particular example, you would need to instantiate the class? This particular class would be likely used on a param block of a function: `[ValidateSet([MyValidValuesAttribute])]`, I'm missing the part where you have an actual need to instantiate it.

Comment: Also, https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/29/Dynamic-ValidateSet/ relevant

Comment: As an aside: `[string[]]'MyValidValueA','MyValidValueB'` should be `[string[]] ('MyValidValueA','MyValidValueB')` instead. Casts have higher precedence than the `,` operator. Without the `(...)`, you'll create an `[object[]]` array whose first element is a nested, single-element `[string[]]` array that contains just `'MyValidValueA'`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I don't intend to instantiate it myself at all! I just need to implement the interface, although I suppose I could pass a value(s) into the constructor to filter,extend, or otherwise influence the valid set, e.g. `[MyValidValues('ValidA')]`?

Comment: That sounds like a good approach, also, the link I provided before shows an excellent example of how you can implement a dynamic set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, **you don't usually need to instantiate an [`IValidateSetValuesGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator)-implementing class *yourself*:** PowerShell does it for you when you use such a class in a [`[ValidateSet()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attribute in order to decorate a parameter in a function's or script's parameter-declaration block (`param(...)`), so as to constrain the arguments passed to that parameter to the set of values returned from the specified class' `.GetValidValues()` instance method.

Note: The `IValidateSetValuesGenerator` interface requires *PowerShell (Core) v6+*; for solutions that also work in *Windows PowerShell*, see [this blog post](https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/29/Dynamic-ValidateSet/) that Santiago found.

---

If you do need to instantiate such a class explicitly:

> instead of the two-line

You can use a single(-line) expression:

```
[MyValidValuesAttribute]::new().GetValidValues()
```

> I know I could just implement `GetValidValues_Static`; wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

If you do need to keep the invocation ceremony to a minimum, you can declare a static *property* as follows, which then allows you to call `[MyValidValuesAttribute]::ValidValues`:

```
Class MyValidValuesAttribute : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
  static [string[]] $ValidValues = [MyValidValuesAttribute]::new().GetValidValues()
  [string[]] GetValidValues() { return [string[]] ('MyValidValueA','MyValidValueB') }
}
```

**Caveat**: Since the static `ValidValues` property is only initialized *once*, the above assumes that that the set of valid values is *static*, which may be at odds with the **intentionally *dynamic* nature of the `IValidateSetValuesGenerator` interface**.

- In fact, **the *dynamic* nature is the reason that the interface defines `.GetValidValues()` as an *instance* method** - situationally, a different set of valid values may be returned; **otherwise, you could simply use the `[ValidateSet()]` attribute with a *static list* of values, such as `[ValidateSet('MyValidValueA', 'MyValidValueB')]`**

**As of v7.2.1, PowerShell doesn't support property *getters*** that are called *on each invocation* - see [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219).

Comment: Thanks, @Santiago, but please see the caveat I've just added.

Comment: Def. upvoted that issue, unfortunately 2016 :(

Comment: Yeah, @Santiago - sadly, it isn't the only issue, there's an entire backlog: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652